# Redirect If User Type = Moderator to a PHP page.... Session and Login

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What am I doing wrong here?

Im planning to redirect a login to a page named administration.php if the user type = moderator..

And so i created a table named users with values in it....
Columns:

1. login
2. password
3. user_type

   ```
                   <?php
                   error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
                   ?>


                   <?php
                   session_start(); 
                   if( $_SESSION["logging"]&& $_SESSION["logged"])
                   {
                    printme(); }



                   else {
                    if(!$_SESSION["logging"])
                       {  
                            $_SESSION["logging"]=true;
                            loginform();
                        }
                    else if($_SESSION["logging"])
                        {
                           $number_of_rows=checkpass();
                           if($number_of_rows==1)
                        {  
                           $_SESSION[user]=$_GET[userlogin];
                           $_SESSION[logged]=true;

                           print"<h1>You have logged in successfully</h1><br/>";
                           print "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a> | <a href='users.php'>Click to proceed</a>"; 
                        }
                           else {

                       print"<br/><br/>";
                       loginform();
                       }
                   }
                }








               function loginform()
               {

               print ("<center><div id='login_header'><b><font face='Arial Black' color='black' size='4px'>Sign in to Minquep!</font></b></div></cen                   ter>");
               print("<br/><br/>");
               print ("<center><label>Username:</label><input type='text' name='userlogin' size='20'><br/><label>Password:</label><input type='                password' name='password' size='20'></center>");
               print "<br/><input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' class='submit'>"; 


               }


               function checkpass()
               {

               $dbHost = 'localhost';
               $dbUser = 'root';
               $dbPass = '';
               $dbname = 'minquep_test';

               $conn = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass); // Connection Code
               mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn); // Connects to database



               $sql="select * from users where login='$_GET[userlogin]' and password='$_GET[password]'";
               $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
               return  mysql_num_rows($result);

               if ($result->user_type == "moderator"){
                   echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=pages/administration.php\">";
               }

               }



               function content(){
               print("<b><h1>hi mr.$_SESSION[user]</h1>");
               print "<br><h2>only a logged in user can see this</h2>";



               }

               function printme(){

               }

               ?>




           </form>
   ```

From that code above^

Im trying to do the scenario but it doesn't work..

**if ($result->user_type == "moderator"){
                        echo "";**

note:
user_type is a column from table named users and I have a record which are the ff:

ID = 1

login = admin

password = shishi

user_type = moderator

Something like that..

how can I do that whenever a user logs in and he's a moderator... he'll automatically redirect to administration.php PAGE.

please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are prematurely returning the number of rows of the resultset before getting to the moderator line.

Try this instead:

```
        $user_login = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['userlogin']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
        $sql = "select * from users where login='$user_login' and password='$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $fetched = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if ($fetched['user_type'] == "moderator"){
            echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=pages/administration.php\">";
        }
```

Comment: What's the best way to fix that line?

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. So now i understand that i called it in a wrong way. + Check for you.

Comment: Lastly, can you tell me the difference of return  mysql_num_rows($result); and the one you used in your answer... Kind of amateur in here. Im having a hard time in fetching things lol

Comment: Essentially, when you query your database, it returns a list of rows as a result. Using `mysql_query` simply sends the request - it does not pull off all the data. Using `mysql_num_rows` will tell you all the rows that mysql_query pulled off the database for you. `mysql_fetch_array` will pull off the next row (in this case, the first one) and you can access the data by placing the strings as indices to the row. For more information: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php

Comment: SQL Injection + Use of deprecated API'

Comment: SQL injection patched. I do not advocate the use of mysql_* functions but it seems that the user is fairly new to MySQL.